# How to upload user profile multiple image from frontend in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, user-profile, image-upload, user-registration

I create my custom registration form plugin at frontend. Now I need that user can upload multiple image and save it on user table and also save it on user profile folder. I use many plugin like [Custom User Profile Photo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-user-profile-photo/developers/) , [Metronet Profile Picture](https://wordpress.org/plugins/metronet-profile-picture) but it not work properly. So please suggest me proper way.

Comment: You can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for this

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageupload($imagename){  
    $uploadedfile = $imagename;
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
   if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) 
   {
       $wp_filetype = $movefile['type'];
       $filename = $movefile['file'];
       $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
       $attachment = array(
         'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
         'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
         'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
         'post_content' => '',
         'post_status' => 'inherit'
           );
      $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename);
      $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
      wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
    } 
    else
    {
       echo $movefile['error'];
    }       
    }     
   $uploadedfile3 = $_FILES['idcard'];  /* First image */
   imageupload($uploadedfile3);
   $uploadedfile1 = $_FILES['Licence']; /*second image*/
   imageupload($uploadedfile1);
   $uploadedfile2 = $_FILES['Agreement']; /*next image*/
   imageupload($uploadedfile2);
```

Comment: You should Explain your answer.

Comment: When every time you call the function with different field name, Then image upload function will call every time for upload you image.

Comment: flow this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882040/upload-media-from-frontend-in-wordpess-using-ajax